# How to read a file one line at a time, on function call

Tags: ruby, file-io, rspec

I am reading a massive file of JSON objects like this:

```
File.open('massive.json') do |file|
  file.lazy.each_slice(BATCH_SIZE) do |lines|
    lines.each do |line|
      employee_data_hash = JSON.parse(line, symbolize_names: true)
      add_employee(employee_data_hash)
    end
  end
end
```

The thing is this, I am finding it tricky to write the correct test for it. Moreover it would be better for the overall design of my project if I could have a function `get_json_line` which would return one line, there is one JSON object per line. Thus I would be able to process the data one line at a time causing no memory problems.

Should I use `yield`? What effects would it have on performance if I use `yield`?

Comment: by line do you mean terminated by a newline character or some other form of separator? If so this method already exists [`IO::foreach`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach) called as `File.foreach('massive.json') { |line| #your logic here }`

Comment: Don't worry about performance until you've tested your code and it proves to be too slow. Using `foreach` is very fast, faster than any `read` based solution once a file gets over 1MB, so you should be fine keeping it a simple loop. `yield` will cause a minor loss in speed, but probably not enough to worry about.

Comment: Ok, so how do I write a test case for it.

Comment: Accept file as an argument the  for your test create a temp file or mock it in some other fashion